# How to pass arguments directy to a class without calling new method?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby a Hash can be created by:

```
Hash(a: 5, b: 6)
```

An Array can be created like this:

```
Array(100)
```

Sets can be created with the code:

```
require 'set'
Set[1,2,3]
```

So, how can I define a class that can accept arguments without calling the initialize method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Ruby a Hash can be created by:
>
> Hash(a: 5, b: 6)

Hash() is actually a method of the Kernel module:

```
p defined?(Hash())           # => "method"
p defined?(Kernel.Hash())    # => "method"
```

But without parentheses, Hash, Array, String, etc. all are just classes:

```
defined?(Hash)     # => "constant"
defined?(Array)    # => "constant"
```

In Ruby 2.6.3, the same goes for Arrays(), Complex(), Float(), Hash(), Integer(), Rational(), String(), and URI() - they all are methods.

But `Set` is a class:

```
require 'set'

p defined?(Set)    # => "constant"
p set = Set[1,2,3] # => #<Set: {1, 2, 3}>
p set.to_a         # => [1, 2, 3]
```

So, Set[1,2,3] is actually calling the [] method of Set. It looks kind of like this:

```
class Something
    def initialize(*a)
        @hash = {}
        a.each { |v| @hash.store(v, nil) }
    end

    def self.[](*a) new(*a) end

    define_method(:to_a) { @hash.keys }

    define_method(:inspect) { "#<#{self.class}: {#{@hash.keys.to_s[1..-2]}}>" }
    alias :to_s :inspect
end

p defined?(Something)                                   # => "constant"
p set = Something[1,2,3]                                # => #<Something: {1, 2, 3}>
p set1 = Something[[1, 2, 3], 2, 2, 3, 4, {4 => :a}, 5] # => #<Something: {[1, 2, 3], 2, 3, 4, {4=>:a}, 5}>

p set.to_a                                              # => [1, 2, 3]
p set1.to_a                                             # => [[1, 2, 3], 2, 3, 4, [4, 4], 5]
```

Back to the question:

> So, how can I define a class that can accept arguments without calling
>   the initialize method?

I don't think it's possible!

Answer (score 5):

> So, how can I define a class that can accept arguments without calling the initialize method?

You can't. In your examples, [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash) and [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) are actually methods.

And example with `Set` uses [Set::[]](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-c-5B-5D), naturally. And so it's not any different from any other class method that returns you instances of that class. For instance, `User::create` (or what-have-you).

Comment: So, for example, Hash() is Kernel.Hash(), Array() is Kernel.Array(), but Set is a constant!! Oh Set[] is a method!

Comment: @S.Goswami: yes, updating.

Comment: Thanks, but you can't define a method with []. `def X[] end` will raise an error. So, what's going on?